# Using Optional to prevent NullPointers In TrainWrecks

Tags: java, option-type, misuse

I was just wondering if the following is the wrong use case for Optional. It probably is, because it looks nasty.

(It is regarding calling "Legacy" code that returns nulls.)

```
  private static class Person {
    private Address address;
    private String name;
  }

  private static class Address {
    private Integer housenr;
    private String houseletter;
    private String street;
  }

  public String getAddress(Person person) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(person.getAddress())
      .map(x -> Optional.ofNullable(x.getHousenr()).map(y -> y + " ").orElse("") +
          Optional.ofNullable(x.getHouseletter()).map(y -> y + " ").orElse("") +
          Optional.ofNullable(x.getStreet()).orElse(""))
      .orElse("<unknown>");
  }

  // unit test if string representation of an address is properly generated
  assertThat(getAddress(charlesBabbage))
      .isEqualTo("4 l Regentstreet");
```

I should probably put the code in a method of the Person class and the Address class, so it doesn't bother me so much.

Or should I do it "the old way":

```
  public String getAddress(Person person) {
    if (person.getAddress() == null) {
      return "<unknown>";
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (person.getAddress().getHousenr() != null) {
      builder.append(person.getAddress().getHousenr() + " ");
    }
    if (person.getAddress().getHouseletter() != null) {
      builder.append(person.getAddress().getHouseletter() + " ");
    }
    if (person.getAddress().getStreet() != null) {
      builder.append(person.getAddress().getStreet() + " ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Bear in mind that this is just an example. More fields can be added like affix., postoffice box, town/city, municipality, state, country (not to mention foreign addresses) exacerbating the problem.

Comment: it's unreadable, just assert the fields individually

Comment: Sorry, @Andrew Tobliko. Clarified the intent of the code.

Comment: both look bad to me, why do you need to build a string? mock "4 l Regentstreet" as an address object and compare 2 objects

Comment: I need to build a string to present it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your examples, you are repeating code that checks that elements are not null before adding them to a String. You can reduce this repetitive work by using Stream and joining:

```
public String getAddress(Person person) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(person.getAddress())
            .map(x -> Stream.of(x.getHousenr(), x.getHouseletter(), x.getStreet())
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
            )
            .orElse("<unknown>");
}
```

Or similarly without Optional:

```
public String getAddress(Person person) {
    Address address = person.getAddress();
    if (address == null) {
        return "<unknown>";
    }
    return Stream.of(address.getHousenr(), address.getHouseletter(), address.getStreet())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it’s the wrong use case at all. True, it is not that easy to read without thinking about formatting and white space, but the way you are using  `Optional` seems fine to me.

For the sake of an assertion, it’s fine to have that (truly ugly) code. I don’t know your final intended use case, but assuming you just want to generate String representations of these objects, I would encapsulate the logic which checks for nulls within the corresponding classes, in a `toString()` method or similar.

*edit:* Nasty looking code does not make its use wrong. Though your coworkers might end up hating you

Comment: While working code is important, nasty code will most likely increase maintenance costs unnecessarily and this is also very important.... OFTEN, more important than "working" code; especially if the life expectancy of the system is years. ALWAYS rethink your strategy if your gut is telling you the code is ugly or unreadable.